# Install Pyscard in python 3.7

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, python-3.7, pyscard

How to install `pyscard` on python 3.7?

Are there other modules for smart card readers in python 3.7?

the error after:

`pip install pyscard`:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

     command: 'c:\allinone\portableapps\python374\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\E4B6~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rgx51osl\\pyscard\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\E4B6~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rgx51osl\\pyscard\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\E4B6~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-o8_63h_7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\E4B6~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rgx51osl\pyscard\
    Complete output (8 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'smartcard.scard._scard' extension
    swigging smartcard/scard/scard.i to smartcard/scard/scard_wrap.c
    swig.exe -python -outdir smartcard/scard -DWIN32 -o smartcard/scard/scard_wrap.c smartcard/scard/scard.i
    error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory


ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\allinone\portableapps\python374\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\E4B6~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rgx51osl\\pyscard\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\E4B6~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rgx51osl\\pyscard\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\E4B6~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-o8_63h_7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly have you failed?

Comment: I failed while trying to do pip install. And I didn’t find how to install on python 3.7

Comment: So you have run `pip install pyscard` in the console. What was the error?

Comment: I add it to the question above

Comment: the reference to `swig.exe` might be [this](http://www.swig.org/).  that said, I don't know this package and I don't use Windows so can't help much!

Comment: there are instructions for windows here: https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/pyscard/blob/master/INSTALL.md maybe try those!

Answer (score 3):

Download swig, latest version.
Unzip it in a folder like `C:\python\Swig` and add that folder to your `PATH`.
Download and install VCPP express from Microsoft, if you don't have.
Then try :

```
pip install pyscard
```

Answer (score 0):

just download
http://www.swig.org/download.html

SWIG is an interface compiler that connects programs written in C and C++ with scripting languages such as Perl, Python, Ruby